# Best option how to find last 2 digits in string with RegEx or LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am trying to get the *last 2 digits* in a string with **RegEx** or **LINQ**.
For example I got these strings:

```
N43OET28W -> result should be 28
N1OET86W  -> result should be 86
S02CT55A  -> result should be 55
M4AKT99A  -> result should be 99
1W24ET39W -> result should be 39
S03KT45A  -> result should be 45
M1AKT23A  -> result should be 23
N1OET35W  -> result should be 35
N12FET42W -> result should be 42
MAKTFDAAD -> result should be null or 0
N3XUK407Q -> result should be 07
MAKT23A   -> result should be 23
```

For now I tried this code:

```
  getIntPattern("N1WET99W");
  getIntPattern("S03KT45A");
  getIntPattern("M1AKT23A");
  getIntPattern("N1OET35W");
  getIntPattern("N1OET42W");
  getIntPattern("MAKTFDAAD");
  getIntPattern("N12FET42W");

  private int getIntPattern(string text)
  {
    int result = 0;
    string m = Regex.Matches(text, @".*?\d+.*?(\d+)")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value).First();
    int.TryParse(m, out result);
    return result;
  }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? The input string doesn't have the same length, and can contain more digits at the beginning. I only need the last two digits.

Comment: What is the expected output (`12` or `45` or `56`) for `"ABC12DEF456XY"`, please?

Comment: only the last 2 digits ,, here 56

Comment: What if the last two digits are separated by a non digit? What would `W875W6` produce?

Comment: If you're looking for a better answer, then shouldn't this be posted on codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: currently my solution doesn't achieve the whole goal .. I 'm not sure about the regex expression. i did build it with the help of a tool..perhaps after we are finished..

Comment: What about XYZ5A2?  Do you want 52 as the last two digits or does having the A in between mean you only want 2 or is that just not a valid use case to worry about?

Comment: @ juharr: XYZ5A2 is not a valid. i must be 2 digits or null/ false

Comment: Then you need a regex like [`Regex.Match(s, "[0-9]{2}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)`](https://ideone.com/6dMUV1) to get the last 2 consecutive digits.

Comment: @biohell So that case doesn't happen or you want it to give you a `null` when it does?  Also what about more that 2 digits in a row like ABCD123?  If you need to validate and extract then stick with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *Linq*: try each 2-letter substring starting from string's end:

```
  string source = "N43OET28W";

  string result = Enumerable
    .Range(2, source.Length - 1)
    .Select(index => source.Substring(source.Length - index, 2))
    .Where(item => item.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you are looking for speed, say, you have *many* items to analyze I suggest `for` loop:

```
  int result = -1;
  int last = -1;

  for (int i = source.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int current = source[i] - '0';

    if (current >= 0 && current <= 9)
      if (last >= 0 && last <= 9) {
        result = current * 10 + last;

        break;
      }
      else
        last = current;
    else
      last = -1;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, your solution does the trick. Everythings theems to be faster that regex...the fastest one it the loop, but for my project the best option the your linq solution.. Thanks!!

Comment: @biohell: the *best* is often a *vague* request (*fastest*, *most readable*, *shortest*). You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this method:

```
public static int? GetLastDigits(string text, int maxDigits = int.MaxValue)
{
    var digits = new Stack<char>();  // Last-in-First-out because we iterate backwards
    for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(text[i]))
            digits.Push(text[i]);
        else if (digits.Count > 0)
            break;
        if (digits.Count == maxDigits)
            break;
    }

    if (digits.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return int.Parse(string.Concat(digits));
}
```

Comment: That would return 123 for ABCD123 instead of 23.  Not sure if that matters based on the examples though.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer. I just used the solution from Dmitry with Linq. Your solution is just like dimitrys really fast !

Answer (score 2):

Your combination of LINQ and regex can be reduced to just regex by some careful design of the regular expression:

```
private static int? GetIntPattern(string text) {
    var m = Regex.Match(text, @"(\d{2})\D*$");
    int res;
    return m != null && int.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, out res) ? (int?)res : null;
}
```

The idea is to "anchor" the two digits to the end of the string with `\D*$`, making it the last two available digits.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/XmDSXv)

Answer (score 0):

here are my two cents. This can be easily achieved with regex and bit of Parallel Linq if performance is key stakeholder.

assuming `data` holds list of text needed to be mined.

```
var rx = new Regex(
    "(\\d{2})(?:(?=\\D$)|$)",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

1)

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var match = rx.Match(item);
    var value = match?.Groups[1].Value;

    Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)?"0":value);
}
```

2)

```
var result = data.AsParallel().Select(
    x =>
    {
        var match = rx.Match(x);
        var value = match?.Groups[1].Value;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "0" : value;
    }).ToArray();

foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

It will emit on screen:

```
28
86
55
99
39
45
23
35
42
0
07
23
```

See full demo at [ideone](https://ideone.com/wgXZtY)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't terribly efficient, but given a `string` extension function `Reverse`

```
public static string Reverse(this string s) => new String(s.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

You can pull out the last two digits as the first two digits with a regular expression:

```
private int getIntPattern(string text) => Convert.ToInt32("0"+Regex.Match(text.Reverse(), @"\d{2}").Value.Reverse());
```

I think most efficient is going to be just scan backwards and find what you are looking for:

```
private int getIntPattern(string text) {
    for (var pos = text.Length - 1; pos > 0; --pos)
        if (Char.IsDigit(text[pos]) && Char.IsDigit(text[pos - 1]))
            return Convert.ToInt32(text.Substring(pos-1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an end anchor, $, to start the search from end of string...

```
string pattern = @"[0-9]{2}(?=[A-Za-z]*$)";
string input = "N43OET28W";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

Explanation: Start from end of string, ignore characters, take 2 digits.

q(?=u): Positive lookahead, match q if it is followed by u

$: end of string anchor

[0-9]{2}: exactly 2 digits